# Typeerror - Steam Jackpot Bot

Tags: undefined, typeerror, steambot

I created a website which is for jackpotting(I didn't buy,it was leaked). Everything is working successfully without one mistake. I couldn't solve it. I need help for this. I googled it but there is no solution.

When i start the bot, there is no problem. After sending trade, i got this error:

```
if(offer.items_to_receive.length > row[0].value) 
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Here is the full code: http://pastie.org/10832102#489-492

This link will navigate you to lines which have problem. I know something about php and mysql. I think this problem exists because bot can't read this row in database.But how can I do it? Need an example.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get information from database and in case of error mysqlConnection.query will callback with err. You should check err before operating with the result. For example, you can set default value for maxitems variable in case of error:

```
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT `value` FROM `info` WHERE `name`=\'maxitems\'', function(err, row, fields) {
            var maxitems = 10;
            if(err || row.length == 0) {
            console.log('Mysql error or empty result:', err);                  
            } 
            else {
            maxitems = row[0].value;
            }  

            if(offer.items_to_receive.length > maxitems) {
            .....   
            }
});
```

Comment: Thank you dude, i'll try it and brb :) This seems more logical than mine.

Comment: You should reestablish mysql connection  after fatal error, because all other mysql query won't work untill you do it.

Comment: I do it from zero. I'll clean all files and database before I re-upload.When I do it,I will write the result here.Thank you bro for your help

Comment: Still fatal error. I reestablished mysql connection. But there is no different result.